# How to uninstall cocos2d templates?

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, cocos2d-iphone, terminal

**Situation:**
 - Just few hours ago I intalled cocos2d 2.x 
 
 - But just before it I delete template files of cocos2d 1.0.1 
 
 - Now I can't see template files of cocos2d 2.x 
 - In Xcode both of the templates are visible, and I can use them. 

**Question:** How I can delete cocos2d 1.0.1 templates, if I already delete files of this templates? Why I can't see files of cocos2d 2.x?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**This will be helpful for those who try to reinstall or delete Cocos2D Templates!**

- If you delete all the files from thi path: ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/
- If you tried to delete it with command in Terminal.app: `cd "your path" ./install-templates.sh -u -f`
- If you tried to reinstall Xcode.app

**Nothing helps?**

***I found solution of this problem!*** 
What you need to do is:

- Open the **Finder**
- Press **Shift-Command-G**
- Enter the Path: /Users/**Your_Username**/Library/Developer
- Press **Go**
- Open **Xcode** Folder
- Open **Templates** Folder
- Delete **Cocos2D** Folder
- Open **File Templates** Folder
- Delete **Cocos2D** Folder

**That's all!**

**P.S** As well you can modify the names of templates and tabs in Xcode. Simply just by renaming folders of the templates.

**P.P.S** By the way right now you can upgrade to Cocos2D 2.x. Download it from here: [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1885)

Comment: What if I deleted cocos2d 2.x, and installed cocos2d 3.x and now i want to reinstall cocos2d 2.x but somehow cannot get it through command line because cocos2d doesnt provide it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 5.1 and later

Command+Alt+G (go to) /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates

Then delete 3d party templates folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this link:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4082
You might need to manually remove the files if all else fails.
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I don't have any files in the folder. So I don't have what to remove.

Comment: Try uninstalling all the templates for both the new versions and the old versions. Then, re-install cocos2d 2x. That should work. ^_^

Comment: How I can uninstall them? I don't have any files for both of them. Can you show me the way?

Comment: You can access the templates here: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
Delete the cocos2d files and that should remove the templates.
You can also use this: ./install-templates.sh -f
to force uninstall and re-install a newer version!
Here's a link:http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1441 Hope that helped ;)

Comment: I told you I didn't have any files in this folder! I already used Terminal. But It didn't help. Is there any way to completely re-install Xcode. Because if you will just deleted and after installed again, they will appear any way.

Comment: Delete "Applications/Install Xcode" you can then re-install from app store. Or open terminal window
cd /Applications
sudo rm -rf Install\ Xcode.app
After that you should be able to reinstall

Comment: Now I will try to re-install I delete Xcode it self + all stuff of Developer at Library. So I think I delete everything that comes with Xcode. Now I downloading it from AppStore.

Comment: I found the way of deleting and re-installing! Unfortunatelly re-installing of Xcode didn't give any result.