# Upgrade cocos2d framework inside project

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocos2d-iphone, upgrade, migrate

I have installed cocos2d project templates and created an application. Now I need to replace a framework files inside the ready project.

I have already replaced templates inside xcode using this:

[How to uninstall cocos2d templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287029/how-to-uninstall-cocos2d-templates)

Is it enough to replace files of cocos2d framework? Or must I create a new project using the new version of template and manually add all the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you upgrade from cocos2d v1 to v2 you need create a new project and copy all your files, but if you upgrade from v2 to v2.x is simple, only need remove all cocos2d files from your project (cocos2d, box2d, cocosDenshion, kazmath.....) and add the new ones.